# How does the holonomy act on the tangent space at a point?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, holonomy

Suppose $(X,h)$ is a compact $n$-dimensional Hermitian manifold, with holonomy group $H$. Now we know,since $X$ is a complex manifold, that $H\subset U(n)$, and that there is a representation of $H$ on the holomorphic tangent space to some point $T_pX\cong \mathbb{C}^n$, which we shall denote as $\rho_{hol}$.

Now the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ has exactly two $n$-dimensional irreducible representations namely the standard representation (i.e. elements of the algebra acting via normal matrix multiplication on $n$ dimensional vectors), $\rho_{st}$ and the representation dual to this, $\rho_{st}^{*}$. This is exercise 15.21 in Fulton and Harris: "Representation Theory". Hence $SU(n)$, as the maximal compact subgroup of $Sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ will also have only two $n$ dimensional irreps. However, $U(n)$ has a non-trivial one dimensional representation 
\begin{align}
&\rho_{det}: U(n) \rightarrow GL(1,\mathbb{C})\\
&\rho_{det}(g)z = \det(g)z
\end{align}
So for each $k$, $\rho_{st}\otimes \rho_{det}^{k}$ is an irreducible $n$ dimensional representation of $U(n)$; thus we have infinitely many $n$-dimensional irreps.

If $(X,h)$ has holonomy $U(n)$,and the holonomy representation $\rho_{hol}$ is irreducible, it should be true that either
\begin{equation}
\rho_{hol} = \rho_{st}\otimes \rho_{det}^{k}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\rho_{hol} = \rho_{st}^{*}\otimes \rho_{det}^{k}
\end{equation}
for some $k$ since these are the only irreducible $n$-dimensional representations. So, is it possible to determine which case is true, and what $k$ is?

Comment: Your claim in the second paragraph is false. For example, $\text{SU}(2)$ has dimension $3$ and only has one irreducible $3$-dimensional representation, and it is not the standard representation (which is $2$-dimensional).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan of course, you are right. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $k$ is $0$ and the representation is the standard one.

The point is that by definition the holonomy group IS a subgroup of U(n).
In particular the action or representation is "faithfull". So to say that the holonomy is U(n) is to say both that the group as abstract group is U(n) and that the action on the tangente space is the standard representation of U(n).

Notice by the way that the representations with $nk + 1$ different from 1 are not faithfull since there exists multiples of the identity acting as the identity. See comment below.

Best,
h.

Comment: Ok I think I see. This is because $H \subset GL(T_pX)$ right? But for the second comment, surely, if $A= diag(e^{2\pi i/nk})$, then $\det(A) = e^{2\pi i/k}$ but, for $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$, $(\rho_{st}\otimes\rho_{det}^k)(A)(v)= \det(A)^k(Av)= Av \neq v$ since $A$ is not the identity, thus this representation is faithful?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. What I had in mind is the following:   Consider  A = m Id. Then A acts on v as :  (m^n)^k m v = m^(nk + 1)v . So as soon nk + 1 is different from 1 you get that the representation is not faithfull i.e. there exist A different from the identity but acting as the identity.

Comment: I forgot: yes, the holonomy group is a subgroup of GL(T_pX) and since it preserves the metric it is contained in O(T_pX). Moreover if (X,h) is Kaehler then the complex structure J is also preserved and H is contained in U(n). Actually, you have to be careful since the usual meaning of Hermitian manifold does not imply that H is contained in U(n) as you claimed. Here I am assuming that you speak about the holonomy group of the Levi-Civita connection associated to h.

Comment: PS: The Iwasawa manifold deeply studied by Simon Salamon and his school is perhaps the best example of an Hermitian manifold which is not Kaehler. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_manifold